# Is it possible to change maven default goal?

Tags: maven-2

Maven newbie question :)

For 'war' packaging,

war:war default goal run in 'package' build phase.

Is it possible to disable war:war ?

I'm using war:exploded instead.

and is it possible to disable 'compile:compile' goal completely ?

I don't use javac at all.

Thank you

Comment: I'm using scala plugin instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unbind a goal so you can't change the default [Built-in Lifecycle Bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings). AFAIK, the only way to disable or replace a goal would be to use a packaging of type `pom` and to rebind everything manually on the various phases.